# How to get Dropdown data using Vue JS?

Tags: javascript, c#, vue.js

my dropdown is not getting any value from my database, it keeps return {{item.cmp_Name}}, Is there anything i have missed?

```
 <label for="user_CompID" class="col-form-label">Company Name</label>
 <select class="form-control" name="user_CompID">
 <option value="">Select Company Name</option>
 <option v-for="item in sel_comp" :value="item.cmp_id">{{item.cmp_Name}}</option></select>
```

Script

```
    var vm = new Vue({
            el: '#maint_user_ctrl',
            data: {
                sel_comp: []
            },
            created: function () {
                this.doLoadParam();
            },
            mounted: function () {
                $(".bt-table").bootstrapTable();

                var dropdownMenu;
                $('.bt-table').on('show.bs.dropdown', function (e) {
                    dropdownMenu = $(e.target).find('.dropdown-menu');
                    $('body').append(dropdownMenu.detach());
                    var eOffset = $(e.target).offset();
                    dropdownMenu.css({
                        'display': 'block',
                        'top': eOffset.top + $(e.target).outerHeight(),
                        'left': eOffset.left
                    });
                });
                $('.bt-table').on('hide.bs.dropdown', function (e) {
                    $(e.target).append(dropdownMenu.detach());
                    dropdownMenu.hide();
                });
            },
            methods: {
                doLoadParam: function () {
                    var self = this;

                    ajaxJsonProcess("get", myPath + "/company-dropdown", "", function (inDat) {
                        self.sel_comp = inDat;
                    }, dftError);

                },
```

i try debug, it getting the dropdown value but not displaying

Answer (score 0):

If you see the string `{{item.cmp_Name}}` instead of the results so you didnt setup vue well from webpack / cli.

Also you should check if the request to the server is send because you have problem there.

Move your `doLoadParams` into `methods` property.

```
{
    created() { ... },
    methods: {
        doLoadParam() { ... }
    }
}
```

Also if you need this request to run when component is mounted you can load the request itself from the `mounted` hook.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are getting the values from the `rest api`. Add `console.log` and confirm you are getting response from Rest api.

```
doLoadParam: function () {
  var self = this;
  ajaxJsonProcess("get", myPath + "/company-dropdown", "", function (inDat) {
    console.log('inDat', inDat)
    self.sel_comp = inDat;
  }, dftError);
}
```

Or else try the below steps

*Step 1:* HTML `template` like

```
<div id="app">
    <label for="user_CompID" class="col-form-label">Company Name</label>
    <select class="form-control" name="user_CompID" v-model="selectedCompany">
      <option value="">Select Company Name</option>
      <option
        :key="index"
        v-for="(item, index) in sel_comp"
        :value="item.cmp_id"
      >
        {{ item.cmp_Name }}
      </option>
    </select>
    {{ selectedCompany }}
  </div>
```

*Step 2:* `data` modal will be

```
data() {
    return {
      selectedCompany: "",
      sel_comp: [],
    };
  },
```

*Step 3:* `methods` loadFromAPI function for loading data from api. I just added dummy data instead of api call.

```
methods: {
    loadFromAPI() {
      // Load from AJAX API
      this.sel_comp = [
        {
          cmp_Name: "Cognizant",
          cmp_id: "cts",
        },
        {
          cmp_Name: "Infosys",
          cmp_id: "infy",
        },
        {
          cmp_Name: "Accenture",
          cmp_id: "acc",
        },
      ];
    },
  },
```

*Step 4:* By default page load get company details from api by `created`

```
created() {
    this.loadFromAPI();
  },
```

[DEMO](https://codesandbox.io/s/charming-pond-xjd0v)

Comment: @CALLMEBBONA is it works for you to load your dropdown list?

Comment: still not working :( but i appreciate for your answer, Thank you!

Comment: @CALLMEBBONA 1. Can you confirm you are getting the response from api?. 2. Can you create codesandbox link?

Comment: @CALLMEBBONA I updated my DEMO link. I implemented to load data from external api. Check and let me know. https://codesandbox.io/s/charming-pond-xjd0v

Comment: hi there! i found out the issue already Thank you so much for your time!

Answer (score 0):

Html

```
<label for="user_CompID" class="col-form-label">Company Name</label>
 <select class="form-control" name="user_CompID" v-model="company">
 <option value="" selected>Select Company Name</option>
 <option v-for="item in sel_comp" :key="item.cmp_id">{{item.cmp_Name}}</option></select>
```

```
Script
data: {        company:'',
               sel_comp: []
           },



mounted: function () {
                //the function can be called in mounted.

                this.doLoadParam();
              

                $(".bt-table").bootstrapTable();

               var dropdownMenu;
               $('.bt-table').on('show.bs.dropdown', function (e) {
                   dropdownMenu = $(e.target).find('.dropdown-menu');
                   $('body').append(dropdownMenu.detach());
                   var eOffset = $(e.target).offset();
                   dropdownMenu.css({
                       'display': 'block',
                       'top': eOffset.top + $(e.target).outerHeight(),
                       'left': eOffset.left
                   });
               });
               $('.bt-table').on('hide.bs.dropdown', function (e) {
                   $(e.target).append(dropdownMenu.detach());
                   dropdownMenu.hide();
               });
           },
```